# One parent is a cystic fibrosis carrier, and the other has no cystic fibrosis gene

Tags: probability

One parent is a cystic fibrosis carrier, and the other has no cystic fibrosis gene. Find the probability of each of the following.

(a) The child would have cystic fibrosis.

Answer = 1/4 = 0.25

(b) The child would be a carrier.

Answer: 2/4 = 0.5  is correct

(c) The child would not have cystic fibrosis and not be a carrier.

answer: 1/4 = 0.25

(d) The child would be healthy (i.e., free of symptoms).

Answer: 3/4 = 0.75

all except part b) are considered wrong and don't know where is the mistake !!!

please any help will be appreciated

Comment: I assume cyctic fibrosis is recessive (i.e. you have symptoms only if both of your copies have the gene)?

Answer (score 1):

Each parent has two copies of the chromosomes and we are given that only one parent has only one bad copy.
The child receives one random chromosome from each parent. Therefore it cannot recieve more than one bad copy.

Assuming that cyctic fibrosis is recessive (i,e. one has symptoms only if both copies are "bad"), the answer to (a) must be $0$ and the asnwer to (d) msut be $1$. Since (b) is correct, it follow sthat the answe to (c) is also $\frac12$ since (b) and (c) must add up to $1$ (we've already seen that "not have cystic fibrosis" is not a restriction).

However, if  cyctic fibrosis is dominant (i,e. one has symptoms as soon as one of the copies is "bad"), the answer to (a) must be $0.5$ (just as for (b))and hence the asnwer to (d) must be the remaining $0.5$. Since "no symptoms" is the same as "no carrier", again the asnwer to (c) sis $0.5$